# Optimization problem with non-linear constraint

Tags: python, linear-programming, pulp, scipy-optimize, mixed-integer-programming

I am new to Optimization problems and working on a simple maximization problem, that i can solve quite simply in Excel. However, I need to scale it in Python and need some help.

I have a menu of different food items, and I need to maximize my energy output. Example:

| Macros | Food | Calorie | Energy |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Protein | Fish | 100 | 60 |
| Protein | Lamb | 200 | 40 |
| Protein | Egg | 200 | 38 |
| Carbs | Banana | 200 | 25 |
| Carbs | Potato | 200 | 30 |
| Carbs | Rice | 200 | 40 |
| Fat | Avocado | 450 | 50 |
| Fat | Cheese | 400 | 60 |
| Fat | Cream | 500 | 55 |

I need to Maximize Energy(e), given the following constraints:

1. Only 1 of the food-items(i) per Macros(m) can be consumed. So I need an indicator variable (0/1) to select only 1 from each of m - Protein, Fat and Carbs.
2. Total number of calories (c) should not exceed a constant value
   Assume 1 portion for each item (no constraint required for this)

**Problem Formulation:**

*Variable:*
X (m,i) → Binary Variable
= {1 , if macro m and item i is chosen, 0 Otherwise}

Maximize e(m,i) * X(m,i)

Parameters:
Calories (C) -> Calories for each (Macro, fooditem)

Subject to Constraints:
For each m, Σ X (m,i) <= 1 (only 1 item per each macro can be selected)
Σ c(m,i) * X(m,i)/ X(i)  <= N  ( calories consumer limited to constant N)

So far, I see this as a Mixed Integer Problem with a Non-linear constraint.

1. I have attempted using Pulp, but it fails due to non-linear constraint. If I remove the non-linearity, it works ok.
2. I attempted with Scipy Optimize, but Scipy doesn't allow to create integer variables.

How can I solve this using Python? Am I misinterpreting the problem here?

**UPDATE:**
The above was missing the non-linear component that gets added due to the `mean`. I updated the problem from a constraint on the `total` to a constraint on the `mean`. In a non-mathematical lingo, I am taking the mean of the number I get after multiplying all the macros since I want my average calories to be less than the constant N.

So mathematically,
Σ c(m,i) * X(m,i)/ X(i)  <= N  ( average calories consumer limited to constant N)

Comment: This sounds like a variation of knapsack problem. A good explanation of algorithms for solving it can be found in this course for example https://www.coursera.org/learn/algorithms-greedy/home/week/4 . Though seeing how you've decided to consider only sets of three elements (one protein, one carb and one fat) I doubt it would take much time to simply bruteforce through the entire list of world's cuisine.  

Also, as far as I know calorie IS the energy value of a food, if we are talking about eating it and not burning or annihilating it.

Comment: @Dimitry it is not an instance of knapsack because of constraint #1. However, some of the solution strategies might be applicable (e.g. branch and bound)

Comment: How many food items and macros are there? A simple bruteforce might be an acceptable solution here

Comment: @Marat You can have more than one constraint in a knapsack problem.  Being as strict as it is, I'd say the first constraint would be the main one for this particular knapsack.

Comment: Thank you for this. Let me check that out. For the sake of scale, brute force might be tricky since I could have anywhere 300 to 2000 food items in total, so would that work?

Also, your suggestion is to see the knapsack python implementation and see if this solution can be implemented similar to knapsack. Correct?

Comment: @DPN 2K items split into 20 categories will result in 100^20 - that's too many variants to brute force. However, if the number of categories is low, it can be feasible (e.g., 2 categories = 1000^2 = 1M variants). It is definitely worth looking at knapsack problem solutions for general education, but don't expect an easy win there - it will still take some learning to adjust it to the constraints

Comment: btw, can you share your dataset? (protip: to get non-OP notified of your response, @mention them)

Comment: Can you share what you have tried so far with PuLP? Btw, I don't see any non-linear constraint in your problem formulation.

Answer (score 5):

As you already mentioned, `scipy.optimize.minimize` can't handle mixed-integer problems (MIP). The most one can do is to try to solve the MIP by a penalty method, i.e. one adds a penalty function to the objective like `1.0/eps * np.sum(x*(1 - x))`, where `eps > 0` is a given penalty parameter and `x` a `np.ndarray`.

However, it's much more convenient to solve the problem with a MIP solver. Since your problem has a well-known knapsack-like structure, you can expect even non-commercial MIP solvers (PuLp uses CBC by default) to utilize your problem's underlying structure. Here, I'd recommend the following formulation:

```
Binary variables:
x[i] = 1 if fooditem i is chosen, 0 otherwise

Parameters:
a[i][m] = 1 if fooditem i covers macro m, 0 otherwise
c[i]        calories for fooditem i
e[i]        energy for fooditem i
N           total calories limit

Model:

max Σ (e[i] * a[i][m] * x[i],  ∀ i ∈ Fooditems, m ∈ Macros)

s.t. Σ (a[i][m] * x[i], ∀ i ∈ Fooditems) <= 1  ∀ m ∈ Macros. (1)
     Σ (c[i] * x[i], ∀ i ∈ Fooditems)    <= N                (2)
```

which can be modelled and solved like this:

```
import pulp

fooditems = {
    'Fish':    {'macro': 'Protein', 'calorie': 100, 'energy': 60},
    'Lamb':    {'macro': 'Protein', 'calorie': 200, 'energy': 40},
    'Egg':     {'macro': 'Protein', 'calorie': 200, 'energy': 38},
    'Banana':  {'macro': 'Carbs',   'calorie': 200, 'energy': 25},
    'Potato':  {'macro': 'Carbs',   'calorie': 200, 'energy': 30},
    'Rice':    {'macro': 'Carbs',   'calorie': 200, 'energy': 40},
    'Avocado': {'macro': 'Fat',     'calorie': 450, 'energy': 50},
    'Cheese':  {'macro': 'Fat',     'calorie': 400, 'energy': 60},
    'Cream':   {'macro': 'Fat',     'calorie': 500, 'energy': 55},
}

# parameters
macros = list({fooditems[i]['macro'] for i in fooditems})
a = {item: {m: 1 if m == fooditems[item]['macro']
            else 0 for m in macros} for item in fooditems}
c = {item: fooditems[item]['calorie'] for item in fooditems}
e = {item: fooditems[item]['energy'] for item in fooditems}
N = 1000

# pulp model
mdl = pulp.LpProblem("bla", pulp.LpMaximize)

# binary variables
x = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("x", fooditems, cat="Binary")

# objective
mdl.setObjective(sum(e[i] * a[i][m] * x[i] for m in macros for i in fooditems))

# constraints (1)
for m in macros:
    mdl.addConstraint(sum(a[i][m]*x[i] for i in fooditems) <= 1)

# constraints (2)
mdl.addConstraint(sum(x[i]*c[i] for i in fooditems) <= N)

# solve the problem
mdl.solve()

print(f"Status: {pulp.LpStatus[mdl.status]}")
for var in mdl.variables():
    print(f"{var.name} = {var.varValue:.0f}")
print(f"energy: {mdl.objective.value()}")
```

This yields

```
Status: Optimal
x_Avocado = 0.0
x_Banana = 0.0
x_Cheese = 1.0
x_Cream = 0.0
x_Egg = 0.0
x_Fish = 1.0
x_Lamb = 0.0
x_Potato = 0.0
x_Rice = 1.0
Energy: 160.0
```

Comment: I like your solution but I notice that some terms in your objective function will always be 0.  Does it help to filter those terms out?     *mdl += pulp.lpSum([e[i] * x[i] for m in macros for i in fooditems if a[i][m]])*

Comment: @Michael No, it's exactly the same. If there's no term containing the variable `x[i]` in the objective expression, pulp will set 0 as the objective coefficient for the variable `x[i]`.

Comment: @joni this is a good example for the solution. Here's why my problem becomes non-linear. In your example code, each of the food items is considered while calculating: a[i][m] * x[i]. The non-linearity is getting added because I need this modification in your problem: sum(a[i][m] * x[i]) / sum(x[i]) - calculating this constraint only based on the food items that got selected by the optimizer and taking the mean of the final set (dividing by the number of food items selected). This is not the exact problem, but I am tweaking the example you have coded to help understand the nonlienarity.

Comment: @joni I realized I had some elements missing from the problem and hence your solution is complete and correct and I will mark this correct. But I also updated my problem to justify the non-linear component.

Comment: @DPN To be honest, your question is not well-phrased. The notation is inconsistent and ambiguous. Also, the additional constraint doesn't match your comment, so it's hard to understand what you are trying to do. I'd highly recommend writing a precise *mathematical* problem formulation. Anyway, assuming you want to add the non-linear constraint `sum(a[i,m]*x[i]) / sum(x[i]) <= N`, you can add the equivalent constraint `sum(a[i,m]*x[i]) <= N * sum(x[i])` instead, which is linear.